# Magento : Error on configuring

Tags: php, magento

I'm Using Mangento Version : 1.7.0.2

When i tried to install with the sample data which magneto, it gives me the following error. Does any have faced similar kind of an issue.

```
   Error in file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\sql\sales_setup  
    \mysql4-upgrade-0.9.16-0.9.17.php" - Can't retrieve entity config: 
    sales/quote_shipping_rate

   Trace:
   #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645):   
   Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
   #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(437):   
   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '0.9.16', '1.6.0.7')
   #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(320):
   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('0.9.16', '1.6.0.7')
   #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): 
   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
   #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): 
   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
   #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): 
   Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
   #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
   #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
   #8 {main}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found the answer for this problem. The Magento version which i was using was 1.7.0.2 and sample data used was magento-sample-data.1.1.2.zip which was not compatible with this version, hence i changed sample data to 1.6.1.zip.

After using this i could able to install the magento.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was i did not update /app/etc/config.xml with the new file and it was lacking info on the core resource model.  Make sure the config.xml fiel is the one that comes with the new version of magento.